# SQL with while loop to DAX conversion

Tags: sql, t-sql, powerbi, dax

Trying to convert the SQL with while loop code into DAX. Trying to build this query without using temp tables as access is an issue on the database and only have views to work with. I believe best option for me is to code it in DAX. Could someone help with it.

```
DECLARE @sd DATETIME
DECLARE @ed DATETIME
SELECT @sd = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-01-31')
SELECT @ed = GETDATE()
DECLARE @date DATETIME = EOMONTH(@sd)

WHILE ( (@date) <= @ed )
BEGIN
SELECT MONTH(@date) as Month, YEAR(@date) as Year, DAY(@date) as Day, A.*
FROM [people] A
WHERE A.effective_date = (SELECT MAX(B.effective_date)
FROM [people] B
WHERE B.employee_id = A.employee_id
AND B.record_id = A.record_id
AND B.effective_date <= @date)
AND A.effective_sequence = (SELECT MAX(C.effective_sequence)
FROM [people] C
WHERE C.employee_id = A.employee_id
AND C.record_id = A.record_id
AND C.effective_date = A.effective_date)
ORDER BY A.employee_id;

SET @date = EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,@date))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* do this as a view, you would either have to hard-code the start and end dates, or filter them afterwards (which is likely to be inefficient). **Instead you can do this as an *inline* Table Valued Function.**

- We can use a [virtual tally-table](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) (generated with a couple cross-joins) to generate a row for each month
- We can use row-numbering instead of the two subqueries

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetData (@sd DATETIME, @ed DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

WITH L0 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) v(n)
),
L1 AS (
    SELECT 1 n FROM L0 a CROSS JOIN L0 b
)
SELECT
  MONTH(m.Month) as Month,
  YEAR(m.Month) as Year,
  DAY(m.Month) as Day,
  p.*  -- specify columns
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.Month, p.employee_id, p.record_id ORDER BY p.effective_date, p.effective_sequence) AS rn
    FROM [people] p
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(month, @sd, @ed) + 1)
            DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, EOMONTH(@sd)) AS Month
        FROM L1
    ) m
    WHERE p.effective_date <= m.Month
) p
WHERE p.rn = 1
;
```

Then in PowerBI you can just do for example

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.GetData ('2021-01-31', GETDATE()) d
ORDER BY
  d.employee_id
```

Note that you *cannot* put the `ORDER BY` within the function, it doesn't work.